# Templates for language learning

Tags: templates, book-design, books

I'd like to make a book for language learning. I intend to include several parts like

1. Conversation;
2. Vocabulary;
3. Grammar;
4. Exercises.

However, the templates for book I got so far seem not suitable for my purpose...I would appreciate any information on how to make such a book using LaTeX or where I can get suitable templates. Thanks!

Comment: For the second part - vocabulary - you can consider to simplify the code from the [bilingual dictionary](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58218/8380) but even a `description` environment would help.

Comment: Please consider to specify which templates were not suitable and mention some details about the design of the book, you would like to achieve.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Your posting, as it stands now, is rather broad, especially as you're note telling us much about which designs you've rejected as being unsuitable and which designs might meet your needs. Please be more specific as to what exactly you're looking to accomplish, design-wise.

Comment: I'm not really seeing the technical question here. There are all sorts of design decisions you might make here, but none of them are linked to the TeX side of things. Once you know what you want, asking how to implement specific elements in LaTeX may well be on-topic.